# How to use sizeThatFits in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uitextview

I have got a text view and a view like this

```
let lb = UITextView()
let view = UIView()
background_img_view.addSubview(about_txt)
```

`lb` doesn't have fixed height,it can be 30 or 300px,how can i use `sizeThatFits` to make `background_img_view`'s height depend on `lb`'s?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
// Get the width you want to fit
let fixedWidth = textView.frame.size.width

// Calculate the biggest size that fits in the given CGSize
let newSize = textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidth, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))

// Set the textView's size to be whatever is bigger: The fitted width or the fixedWidth
textView.frame.size = CGSize(width: max(newSize.width, fixedWidth), height: newSize.height)

// Make the "background_img_view" height match the textView's height
background_img_view.frame.size.height = textView.frame.size.height
```

Comment: Could you add some comments to each line of code to say what it does?