# UITextView calculates height wrong if text input by copy paste

Tags: ios, swift, textview

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {

    let fixedWidth: CGFloat = textView.frame.size.width

    let newSize: CGSize = textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidth, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))

    delegate.updateHeightTextView(height: newSize.height)

    return true
}
```

I calculate the textview height in above function.
It works well when I type in some text, but when I copy and paste text, it isn't correct.

Comment: 1. What is this `sizeThatFits` method? 2. Your code does not take into account the proposed changes. Remember, `shouldChangeTextIn` is called *before* the text view is actually updated. 3. Your code doesn't work properly even when typing.

Comment: observe textView's text property and calculate size on text change
You can use RxCocoa for observation perpose

Comment: @rmaddy I updated my code.

Comment: When I typing, newSize return correct, but when I paste text, it isn't correct

Comment: The updates you made have nothing to do with my comments.

Comment: @rmaddy textView.sizeThatFits() return size textview, and it works when I typing. It's true
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42790079/how-to-use-sizethatfits-in-swift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution. Instead of calculate height textview in
 `- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text;`
 I calcuated it in 
`- (void)textViewDidChangeSelection:(UITextView *)textView;`

If I calculate in 
`textViewDidChange`
It's not called if I type first charactor or paste some text at first.

Answer (score 1):

in your case, you have to calculate TextView's height as long as TextView's text changes.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(textDidChange) name:UITextViewTextDidChangeNotification object:nil];

- (void)textDidChange{
    //calculate the height here
}
```

[UITextViewTextDidChangeNotification](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextviewtextdidchangenotification)

Comment: my textViewDidchange not call when I typ first charactor or paste some text at first. So I used: textViewDidChangeSelection(_ textView: UITextView) {}
It worked!

Answer (score 1):

You can choose different methods for changing the height.

Most easiest way is to set:

```
textView.isScrollEnabled = false
```

or

Uncheck

```
Scrolling Enabled
```

property of textview on story board
[image]

Here the height of the text view will change according to the content.

Another way is to calculate the height inside the textView delegate method

```
func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {

}
```

Comment: I used 
    func textViewDidChangeSelection(_ textView: UITextView) {}
because my textViewDidChange() not call when I type first charactor or paste some text at first.
And my textview put inside a tableviewcell, so I must update cell height

Comment: set the delegates  and use the delegates methods inside the cell class.

Answer (score 0):

method `sizeThatFits` returns correct size for changes from copy, paste, delete selected text.

```
    func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
        let contentSize = textView.sizeThatFits(
            .init(
                width: textView.contentSize.width,
                height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude
            )
        )
    }
```